# Mobile app with multiple social logins and contacts fetching strategy

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api

My iOS app offers to the users to login using Facebook, Google+, Twitter or with a custom account. After the login, the user can connect all its social accounts to his account.

The app fetches the user contacts from all the social accounts he has connected.

**Scenario 1**: New user logs in with Facebook account

- the user logs in with Facebook account, the app is authorized from Facebook and an access token is retrieved, so the app has all the details to proceed with fetching the contacts.
- while the app is open, the user connect with his Google+ account, the app is authorized and it contains the access token
- The app tries to fetch the Facebook and Google contacts -> OK

**Scenario 2**: Existing user logs in with Facebook account

The app has a fresh Facebook access token, but not a fresh Google+ access token, also if he already authorised the app and the 2 account details are merged.

- How can I retrieve the Google contacts?
- Is it possible to do it without asking again the user to authorize again the app?

Same scenario can be applied in the case user logs in with Google+ and he want to update the Facebook contacts.

Thanks

Comment: _“the app is authorized from Facebook and an access token is retrieved, so the app has all the details to proceed with fetching the contacts”_ – and how exactly would fetching those contacts work …? You are aware that with API v2, your app will only be able to see friends of the current user that are also users of the same app already, right?

Comment: @CBroe, yes I know, but that's not the issue....

Answer (score 0):

Many users sync their Facebook / Google contacts to the Contacts list on their device. You can join this list with users from your database using their emails, and then you have a list of their friends who also use your app. Obviously you have to store users emails in your backend this way, but if you're allowing them to login with multiple social networks, you'll want to do this because then you can map Facebook / Google / Twitter to one user in your app through their email. You also get the added benefit of displaying any friends who they've manually entered into their contact list. I think this is the easiest way.

If you want to go the route of connecting multiple social networks through your app then you would get friends from each social network who use your app through each of the API's (again joining with emails).